# Why does IsDisposed return false after calling Dispose()?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I am trying to clear all items from a ToolStripDropDownButton.
Since they are disposable, I call the dispose method on each of them.
But I see that after calling the dispose() method, the IsDisposed property still returns false.
Why is that and how can I check if Dispose() is called on any object ?
It is not a problem (I hope) in my current project, but I would really like to know what is going on here...

my code so far :

```
private void ClearDropDownAccessConnections()
{
    ToolStripItem button = null;

    for (int i = toolStripDropDownButtonAccess.DropDownItems.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        button = toolStripDropDownButtonAccess.DropDownItems[i] as ToolStripItem;
        if ((button.Tag != null) && ((int)button.Tag == 10))
        {
            toolStripDropDownButtonAccess.DropDownItems.Remove(button);
            button.Dispose();
            //IF I CHECk HERE THEN button.IsDisposed IS STILL FALSE                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ToolStripItems are "lean" controls, they don't use a window.  And don't derive from the Control class.  That often means that they don't actually have anything worth disposing.  Makes them pretty buggy too.

Comment: [More info on `IDisposable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/2478357).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever their reason, the original .NET developers have decided to flip the `IsDisposed` flag only if the disposed `ToolStripItem` has non-null `Owner` property (which you're kindly indirectly setting to `null` line before). This doesn't seem to have any further impact - i.e. you can assume the `ToolStripItem` is safely disposed despite this weird behaviour.

As for your broader question - the `IDisposable` interface does not provide any way of checking if the object was disposed (and to make matters worse - classes implementing it do not have to guarantee an exception-free execution if it's called more than once (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx))). You need to rely on the developers of said classes to provided some info if the object was actually disposed (which as can be seen in the `ToolStripItem` example is not a fool proof method), or track this somehow in your code.

Having said all that, it rarely becomes a problem in real-life scenarios (though it's useful to be aware of it).

Comment: Why don't the .NET developers give us a .Free method like in Delphi.

Comment: @user3611669 Mainly because one of the major ideas behind .NET is that you do not need a `Free` function, i.e. memory is managed by the runtime environment, not the developer (I don't want to get into a discussion on pros and cons). .NET's `Dispose` != Delhpi's `Free` (at least to the best of my limited understanding of Delphi), as in most normal scenarios `Dispose` will not affect the amount of free memory.